# Javascript/HTML5 - simple File system not working

Tags: javascript, html, html5-filesystem

I decided to try out the HTML5 File System API, so I typed up a simple example from a tutorial:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {

    window.requestFileSystem  = window.requestFileSystem || window.webkitRequestFileSystem;

    function initFs (fs) {
        console.log(fs);
    }

    function fsErr (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }

    window.requestFileSystem(window.TEMPORARY, 5*1024*1024, initFs, fsErr);

});
```

When I run this, a `FileError` object it logged(with a code of 2). Also, I am using windows(I say that because I thought this might have something to do with system security)

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: does the page url start with "http" as seen in the address bar?

Comment: It's a local file on my PC, so no, the page url starts with `File:///`

Comment: that's probably not going to work, use a web server and try again; the code looks fine at a glance...

Comment: Ok. Why does it need to run on a server? It's just client code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are seeing is a `SECURITY_ERROR`.  See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileError?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FFileError for more details.  This is because you are using the `file:` protocol.  You have 2 ways around this:

1. Serve files from a (local) webserver.
2. Use Chrome and launch with the `--allow-file-access-from-files` flag.

In general, the file system is meant to access sandboxed local files, so you can't access just any file on disk (this would be a massive security hole).  So, you can't just read/write to `C:\My Documents\my_credit_card_numbers.txt`.

A really great tutorial is available at [HTML5 Rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/)